# Bash : Huge file size processing issue in vim mode

Tags: bash, unix, vim, awk, sed

I have a huge file size of about `500MB` and each line will have data something like mentioned below.

```
#vim results.txt
{"count": 8, "time_first": 1450801456, "record": "A", "domain": "api.ai.", "ip": "54.240.166.223", "time_last": 1458561052}
{"count": 9, "time_first": 1450801456, "record": "A", "domain": "cnn.com.", "ip": "54.240.166.223", "time_last": 1458561052}
 .........
```

25 Million lines are in total.

Now , I would like to keep the `results.txt` file as ,

```
8,1450801456,A,api.ai,54.240.166.223,1458561052
9,1450801456,A,cnn.com,54.240.166.223,1458561052
....
```

By removing the unwanted strings like count , time_first , record ,domain , ip , time_last.

Right now , In vim mode i'm removing each and every string. For example, I would do `%s/{"count": //g`  .

For one string  , It took more time to replace it.

I'm a beginner in Bash/shell, How can i do this using `sed / awk` ? Any suggestions please ?

Comment: There are thousands of awk and sed examples easily found by doing a precursory google search. They aren't some obscure libraries

Comment: Would you be getting this type of file once a day/week/month? or is it a one time thing? If its a one time thing, sure vim. Otherwise, sed.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi This would be a frequent data( Daily ) that comes to me for processing.

Comment: @Arun then use sed, like redFIVE said, its an easy google, you'll have to break it down by operation. If you get lost (after you have tried a few things) ask another question here.

Comment: `vim` and `sed` use almost the same commands.  Remove the leading `%` and place your command inside single quotes.  Redirect the output to a new filename (DO NOT redirect to the same filename,the shell will truncate it to zero bytes).

Comment: not sure why i'm getting down voted. Is this a lame question ?

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but it does not show much effort on your part to try to find a solution.  If you tried something already then show what you tried and what happened.

Comment: Yes it is. I didn't downvote it but a quick google search would've produced the answer for you so I assume that lack of effort is what's driving the downvotes.

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Yes , Already doing that mate. Will update the post, if i come across any issues .

Comment: @EdMorton Was in a real hurry to work on the huge data. I taut , If i got some idea from here , I can try to use it to solve some other problem similar to it and that's the way i learn from here.  Thanks for the suggestions. Will try to check things out.

Comment: @cdarke : I was trying to replace each and every string manually in vim mode . For example :%s/{"count": //g , :%s/ "time_first": //g , %s/ "record": //g . But one replace is consuming huge time .

Comment: stop trying to use vim for this, you need sed, awk, or cut.

Comment: All , Finally tried Example: sed -i 's/{"count": //g;s/ "time_first": //g;s/ "rrtype": //g' test.txt . I got the results what i expected. Thanks all

Comment: @EdMorton Yes , done using sed . Thanks

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Thanks mate !

Comment: @cdarke Thanks done using sed .

Comment: Hence proved that i'm lazy !

Comment: @redFIVE Thanks mate.

Comment: "This would be a frequent data( Daily ) that comes to me for processing" why do you receive that data if you don't know what to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With sed:

```
sed -E 's/[{ ]*"[^"]*": *|["}]//g' file
#    ^    ^    ^         ^^---- remaining double quotes and the closing bracket
#    |    |    |         '----- OR
#    |    |    '--------------- key enclosed between double quotes
#    |    '-------------------- leading opening curly bracket and spaces
#    '------------------------- use ERE (Extended Regular Expression) syntax
```

Other way: using [xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) that includes a json parser:

```
xidel -q file -e '$json/*' | sed 'N;N;N;N;N;y/\n/,/'
#     ^           ^     ^         ^         ^---- translate newlines to commas
#     |           |     |         '-------------- append the next five lines
#     |           |     '------------------------ all values
#     |           '------------------------------ for each json string
#     '------------------------------------------ quiet mode
```

Shorter way from @BeniBela that doesn't need `sed` to join the fields together:

```
xidel -q file -e '$json/join(*,",")'
```

Comment: xidel some thing new for me  and to learn as well . Thanks for sharing .

Comment: @Arun: note that xidel isn't a unix/linux common tool and must be installed. I added a way with it since this utility is very useful (for JSON, XML, HTML), powerful and tolerant.

Comment: Will install it on my linux machine and will try to use that out on most of my works. Thanks

Comment: You do not need sed here. Xidel reads the file as sequence of objects and you can then map each object: `xidel -q file -e '$json/join(*, ",")'`. Although it keeps all the data in memory, which might be a bad idea with such big files

Comment: @BeniBela: Thanks, I was looking for something like this but I didn't find it.

Answer (score 3):

Something to consider:

```
$ awk -F'[{}":, ]+' -v OFS=, '{for (i=3;i<NF;i+=2) printf "%s%s", $i, (i<(NF-1)?OFS:ORS)}' file
8,1450801456,A,api.ai.,54.240.166.223,1458561052
9,1450801456,A,cnn.com.,54.240.166.223,1458561052
```

Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins.

Comment: Ed : Many Thanks for your answer on this . Tried using sed finally : sed -i 's/{"count": //g;s/ "time_first": //g;s/ "rrtype": //g;s/ "rrname": //g;s/ "rdata": //g;s/ "time_last": //g;s/}//g' test.txt

Comment: Thanks for the reference, If I have the time, I will read it.

Comment: @Arun there no need to hard-code all those text strings, the right approach with ANY tool is to just use their relative positions on each line or define a regexp to strip select what you want (or don't want).